# flex mobile using badges in elements

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, badge

Is there a way to display so called badges in Flex elements?

With badges I mean the little red circles with a number in it which are used to display the amount of new items in a inbox by example.

I want to display badges in a flex list or tabbed item.

Is this core functionality of Flex?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do this in Flex, but it will likely (without seeing your designs, etc) require implementing a custom item renderer for the list.  For an example of doing this for a Flex-based web or AIR app, look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS03d33b8076db57b9-23c04461124bbeca597-8000.html).  Also, you will likely want to read up on Flex 4 [skinning](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS53116913-F952-4b21-831F-9DE85B647C8A.html)  for writing a custom skin for your list item renderers, as well as perhaps the list itself.  Additionally, if you are, as implied by your tags, writing a flex mobile app, you'll want to read up on [building mobile item renderers](https://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2011/6/24/Building-a-Mobile-ItemRenderer-in-Flex) as they differ in subtle, but important ways from standard web-based Flex or desktop AIR apps.
 The short answer, then, is yes, but you will likely need to write some custom code to get things exactly the way you want them, styling-wise and behaviorally.

Comment: Ok, thanks, will read the articles. It's not in Flex by default I understand.

Answer (score 0):

How did you do? I use the next snippet for a badge in a tabbed item. http://blog.aboutme.be/2011/10/28/flex-mobile-tabbed-view-navigator-button-badge/

I hope it helps you.